# PHP - XML RPC error

Tags: php, xml, rpc

Could someone help me with XML - RPC?
I use the library xmlrpc http://gggeek.github.io/phpxmlrpc/ version 4.0.0

I do not know how to call the getData and into the result.
I'm constantly returns an error 17

Thanks all!!

**This is my "server" class.**

```
class xmlrpc_server (

    public function run(){

            $this->getMethods();
            $this->server = new PhpXmlRpc\Server($this->methods);

    }


    public function getMethods(){

            $this->methods = array(

                "getData" => array(
                    "function" => "getData",
                    "signature" => array( array( PhpXmlRpc\Value::$xmlrpcArray, PhpXmlRpc\Value::$xmlrpcInt   )),
                    "docstring" => "Auth server - getData (with AUTH ID)." 
                )          

            );

    } 



    function getData($m){

            $mydata = array();
            $mydata['user_id'] = $m->getParam(0); //sended user ID

            return PhpXmlRpc\Response( $myexport, "array" );

    }


}
```

**Client class**

```
class client( 

  public function send(){

                  $this->user_id      = 123456;

                  PhpXmlRpc\PhpXmlRpc::$xmlrpc_internalencoding = 'UTF-8';
                  $this->server_connect = new xmlrpc_client('/index.php', 'myserver.com', 80);

                  $params         = array(new xmlrpcval($this->user_id, 'int'));
                  $msg            = new xmlrpcmsg('getData', $params); //call 'getData'
                  $response       = $this->server_connect->send($msg);  //send and get response

                  print_r($response);  //print response

  }

)

$client = new client;
$client->send();
```

**And results from print_r()**

```
PhpXmlRpc\Response Object
(
    [val] => 0
    [valtyp] => 
    [errno] => 17
    [errstr] => Internal server error: no function matches method
    [payload] => 
    [hdrs] => Array
        (
            [date] => Sat, 11 Feb 2017 13:57:40 GMT
            [server] => Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
            [vary] => Accept-Charset,Accept-Encoding
            [content-encoding] => gzip
            [content-length] => 201
            [connection] => close
            [content-type] => text/xml; charset=UTF-8
        )

    [_cookies] => Array
        (
        )

    [content_type] => text/xml
    [raw_data] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 11 Feb 2017 13:57:40 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Vary: Accept-Charset,Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 201
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

The fatal error is in the definition of the dispatch map: `"function" => "getData"` should be `"function" => array( $this, "getData")`

Otherwise the xmlrpc server will be looking for a global php function 'getData' to execute when receiving the xmlrpc call, instead of looking for its own method.

As a side note: in your example you also should fix `return PhpXmlRpc\Response( $myexport, "array" );` to be `return new PhpXmlRpc\Response( new PhpXmlRpc\Value( $myexport, "array" ) );`